# Android MediaPlayer cannot play files that contain '#' character in the file name using Uri.parse(path)

Tags: java, android, uri

From what I can tell, the Uri.parse in my code is causing my MediaPlayer to fail on audio files with special characters in the filename, like "#" and others. I cannot figure out how to resolve this issue. I want to be able to use special characters in my filenames. Here is the code that I think is causing the issue:

```
public void playAudio(int media) {
        try {
            switch (media) {
                case LOCAL_AUDIO:
                    /**
                     * TODO: Set the path variable to a local audio file path.
                     */
                   if (path == "") {
                        // Tell the user to provide an audio file URL.
                        Toast
                                .makeText(
                                        MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.mp,
                                        "Please edit MediaPlayer_Audio Activity, "
                                                + "and set the path variable to your audio file path."
                                                + " Your audio file must be stored on sdcard.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(sound_loop);
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.mp, Uri.parse(path));
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    resetTimer();
                    startTimer();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.PLAY_START);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);  


                    break;
                case RESOURCES_AUDIO:
                    /**
                     * TODO: Upload a audio file to res/raw folder and provide
                     * its resid in MediaPlayer.create() method.
                     */
                   // mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_cbr);
                    //mMediaPlayer.start();

            }
            //tx.setText(path);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
```

I am using MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.java to play sounds. As you can see from the above code, the mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.mp, Uri.parse(path)); is calling the code to retrieve the file and media player, I think. I am not too skilled with android code yet. Here is the code for MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.java:

```
public class MediaPlayerDemo_Audio extends Activity {

public static String path;
private String fname;

private static Intent PlayerIntent;
public static String STOPED = "stoped";
public static String PLAY_START = "play_start";
public static String PAUSED = "paused";
public static String UPDATE_SEEKBAR = "update_seekbar";

public static boolean is_loop = false;
private static final int LOCAL_AUDIO=0;


private Button play_pause, stop;
private SeekBar seek_bar;

public static MediaPlayerDemo_Audio mp;
private AudioPlayerService mPlayerService;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.media_player_layout);
    //getWindow().setTitle("SoundPlayer");
    //getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, 
        //  android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

    play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
    play_pause.setOnClickListener(play_pause_clk);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(stop_clk);
    seek_bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seek_bar.setMax(100);
    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {              
            if (mPlayerService!=null) {
                int seek_pos = (int) ((double)mPlayerService.getduration()*seekBar.getProgress()/100);
                mPlayerService.seek(seek_pos);                
            }
        }
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {


        }
    });

    play_pause.setText("Pause");
    stop.setText("Stop");        

    //int idx = path.lastIndexOf("/");
    //fname = path.substring(idx+1);
    //tx.setText(path);


    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(STOPED);
    filter.addAction(PAUSED);
    filter.addAction(PLAY_START);
    filter.addAction(UPDATE_SEEKBAR);

    registerReceiver(mPlayerReceiver, filter);

    PlayerIntent = new Intent(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.this, AudioPlayerService.class);
    if (AudioPlayerService.path=="") AudioPlayerService.path=path;
    AudioPlayerService.sound_loop = is_loop;
    startService(PlayerIntent);
    bindService(PlayerIntent, mConnection, 0);  
    if (mPlayerService!=null && mPlayerService.is_pause==true) play_pause.setText("Play");
    mp = MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.this;

}

private BroadcastReceiver mPlayerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String act = intent.getAction();
        if (act.equalsIgnoreCase(UPDATE_SEEKBAR)){
            int val = intent.getIntExtra("seek_pos", 0);
            seek_bar.setProgress(val);
            TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
            counter.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime((long) (intent.getLongExtra("time", 0)/16.666)));
            //tx.setText(fname);
        }
        else if (act.equalsIgnoreCase(STOPED)) {
            play_pause.setText("Play");             
            seek_bar.setProgress(0);
            stopService(PlayerIntent);
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mPlayerService = null;
            TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
            counter.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));
        }
        else if (act.equalsIgnoreCase(PLAY_START)){
            play_pause.setText("Pause");
        }
        else if (act.equalsIgnoreCase(PAUSED)){
            play_pause.setText("Play");
        }

    }
};
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
        mPlayerService = ((AudioPlayerService.LocalBinder)arg1).getService();
        if (mPlayerService.is_pause==true) {
            play_pause.setText("Play");
            seek_bar.setProgress(mPlayerService.seek_pos);
        }
        if (mPlayerService.mTime!=0) {
            TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
            counter.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime((long) (mPlayerService.mTime/16.666)));
        }
        if (path.equalsIgnoreCase(AudioPlayerService.path)==false){
            AudioPlayerService.path = path;
            mPlayerService.restart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mPlayerService = null;
    }
};
private OnClickListener play_pause_clk = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (mPlayerService!=null)
            mPlayerService.play_pause();
        else{
            AudioPlayerService.path=path;
            startService(PlayerIntent);
            bindService(PlayerIntent, mConnection, 0);
        }
    }

};
private OnClickListener stop_clk = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (mPlayerService==null) return;
        mPlayerService.Stop();          
    }

};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

}

How can I fix this issue so files can be parsed with special characters and played correctly in MediaPlayer? Am I missing something?

Maybe it would help to show the entire code for my AudioPlayerService:

```
public class AudioPlayerService extends Service {
public MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
protected long mStart;
public long mTime;
public int seek_pos=0;
public static boolean sound_loop = false;
public boolean is_play, is_pause;
public static String path="";
private static final int LOCAL_AUDIO=0;
private static final int RESOURCES_AUDIO=1;    

private int not_icon;
private Notification notification;
private NotificationManager nm;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private Intent intent;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    playAudio(LOCAL_AUDIO);
    mTime=0;

    is_play = true;
    is_pause = false;

    CharSequence ticker = "Touch to return to app";
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    not_icon = R.drawable.play_notification;
    notification = new Notification(not_icon, ticker, now);

    nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();   
    intent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);


    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //INCOMING call
                //do all necessary action to pause the audio
               if (is_play==true && is_pause==false){
                   play_pause();
               }

            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //Not IN CALL
                //do anything if the phone-state is idle
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold
                //do all necessary action to pause the audio
                //do something here
                 if (is_play==true && is_pause==false){
                    play_pause();
                 }
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };//end PhoneStateListener

    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(mgr != null) {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    OnAudioFocusChangeListener myaudiochangelistener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int arg0) {
            //if (arg0 ==AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK){
                 if (is_play==true && is_pause==false){
                    play_pause();
                 }
            //}

        }

    };

    AudioManager amr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    amr.requestAudioFocus(myaudiochangelistener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();   
    String title = "VoiceRecorder App";
    CharSequence message = "Playing..";
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message,pendingIntent);
    nm.notify(101, notification);
     return START_STICKY;
 }
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    AudioPlayerService getService() {
        return AudioPlayerService.this;
    }
}
public void restart(){
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    playAudio(LOCAL_AUDIO);
    mTime=0;

    is_play = true;
    is_pause = false;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return mBinder;
}
 private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

 public void Stop()
 {          
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.STOPED);
    sendBroadcast(intent1); 

    resetTimer();

    is_play=false;
    is_pause=false;
 }
 public void play_pause()
 {
     if (is_play==false){
        try {
             mMediaPlayer.start();         
             startTimer();       

             is_play=true;
             is_pause = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.PLAY_START);
        sendBroadcast(intent);  
    }
    else{
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
        stopTimer();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.PAUSED);
        sendBroadcast(intent1); 

        is_play = false;
        is_pause = true;
    }

 }
 public int getduration()
 {
     return mMediaPlayer.getDuration(); 
 }

 public void seek(int seek_pos)
 {
     mMediaPlayer.seekTo(seek_pos);
     mTime = seek_pos;
 }
  public void playAudio(int media) {
        try {
            switch (media) {
                case LOCAL_AUDIO:
                    /**
                     * TODO: Set the path variable to a local audio file path.
                     */
                   if (path == "") {
                        // Tell the user to provide an audio file URL.
                        Toast
                                .makeText(
                                        MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.mp,
                                        "Please edit MediaPlayer_Audio Activity, "
                                                + "and set the path variable to your audio file path."
                                                + " Your audio file must be stored on sdcard.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(sound_loop);
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.mp, Uri.parse(path));
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    resetTimer();
                    startTimer();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.PLAY_START);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);  


                    break;
                case RESOURCES_AUDIO:
                    /**
                     * TODO: Upload a audio file to res/raw folder and provide
                     * its resid in MediaPlayer.create() method.
                     */
                   // mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_cbr);
                    //mMediaPlayer.start();

            }
            //tx.setText(path);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mTime += curTime-mStart;
            mStart = curTime;

            int pos = (int) ((double)mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()*100/mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            seek_pos = pos;
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.UPDATE_SEEKBAR);
            if (mMediaPlayer.isLooping()) intent1.putExtra("time", (long)mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            else intent1.putExtra("time", mTime);
            intent1.putExtra("seek_pos", pos);      
            sendBroadcast(intent1);

            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()==false && mMediaPlayer.isLooping()==false){                
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                resetTimer();
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.STOPED);
                sendBroadcast(intent2);
                is_play=false;
            }           
            if (mTime > 0) mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 10);
        };
    };
    private void startTimer() {
        mStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mHandler.removeMessages(0);
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        mHandler.removeMessages(0);

    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        stopTimer();
        mTime = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
        nm.cancel(101);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For local files, do not use `Uri.parse()`. Use `Uri.fromFile()`, passing in a `File` object pointing to the file in question. This should properly escape special characters like `#`.

Comment: That worked! I saw that solution in another post and tried to implement it but I guess I must not have done it correctly before. Thanks!

Comment: I changed all the instances of Uri.parse to Uri.fromFile as suggested but now my sound files included in the app won't play. Uri.fromFile plays recorded sounds saved to phone with special characters like "#" in them (I have a voice recorder app), but it will not play any of the bundled sounds already in the app. Uri.parse plays all sounds in the app, except for ones with special characters like "#" in the file name. I've tried to add if logic to all the instances where Uri.parse is called, but not every instance can accept the if statement for when my sounds are from the app, not the phone.

Comment: @NickLopez: "but it will not play any of the bundled sounds already in the app" -- I do not know what "bundled sounds" means from a technical standpoint. Are they raw resources? Assets? Files that you download on first run? Files that you randomly generate? Something else?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear with that one. From the technical standpoint, the "bundled sounds" are raw resources that are included in my app. The raw resources cannot be renamed by the user, but the recorded sounds can. What I am trying to avoid is the media players in my app from failing if a user renames a sound and adds a special character like "#" in the name. I can prevent that error by changing to Uri.fromFile, but then the raw resources don't play..

Comment: @NickLopez: "From the technical standpoint, the "bundled sounds" are raw resources that are included in my app" -- use [the `create()` factory method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) for that.

Comment: How would I implement this in my above code? MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create()? Do I still use Uri.fromFile and will it work for both raw resources and external sources with special characters in the name?

Comment: @NickLopez: When you are loading a raw resource, use `MediaPlayer.create()` instead of `new MediaPlayer()`, such as via an `if` statement. "Do I still use Uri.fromFile" -- no. You supply the ID of the raw resource to `create()` (e.g., `R.raw.something`).

Comment: Okay but how can I use an if statement to call whether the sound is a raw resource or not? I use an array to select my sounds in GridView from my sounds activity.

Comment: @NickLopez: Your array can be an array of some interface or base class (e.g., `SoundItem`), with implementations/subclass per data store (e.g., `FileSoundItem`, `ResourceSoundItem`). Those items can have a `buildMediaPlayer()` that returns the populated `MediaPlayer` instance, with the appropriate implementation (`MediaPlayer.create()` for `ResourceSoundItem`, `new MediaPlayer()` and `setDataSource()` for `FileSoundItem`). I am sure that there are any number of other patterns for this.

Comment: Based on my above code, is there an easy way to do this? I've tried calling several different if statements to the `mMediaPlayer` code, but nothing is working. I'm still new to android so forgive my lack of grasp. My code uses a `switch` to call `case LOCAL_AUDIO` and `case RESOURCES_AUDIO` but only the `case LOCAL_AUDIO` is called in `onCreate()` and `restart`. How can I call both cases in my above `AudioPlayerService` code? Can you point me in the right direction? I think I've just been staring at it for too long..

Comment: @commonsware you are a rock&roll hero and steely eyed missleman. There is no validation method for android file names so your method is perfect.

I would add that using "parse" is good for displaying the filename, but "fromFile" is the only method that produces valid filenames for loading.